# Numerical solution of Bessel-like equation using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I need to calculate solution of Bessel-like equation having general form:
$\frac{d^2F}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{dF}{dr}+Q(r)F(r)=0$. Problems come from the points near $r=0$ leading to numeric errors.

For example, simple Bessel equation can be solved using DSolve:

```
DSolve[{y''[x] + 1/x y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

with output:

```
{{y[x] -> BesselJ[0, x]}}
```

However same equation using NDSolve produces errors:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 1/x y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]

Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`. >>
```

The question is: how to overcome erros in NDSolve routine and get numeric solution?

Comment: Is this the whole story? I get errors when I run your `DSolve`, though I also get the answer you show.

Comment: You can substitute the `0` making trouble with a small number : `sol[x_] = 
 First[y[x] /. 
   NDSolve[{y''[x] + 1/x y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[$MachineEpsilon] == 1, 
     y'[$MachineEpsilon] == 0}, y[x], {x, $MachineEpsilon, 10}]]`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with the initial conditions. At $x=0$ there is no solution. The analytical solution given by Mathematica seems to have used the standard solution for standard Bessel ODE http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html, which is a Bessel function. But I am not sure for $n=0$ one can just use Bessel(0,x), I think BesselY(0,x) is also needed.
This is what I get.

But to answer you, I think you need to use series solution for this. Or avoid $x=0$ as was suggested in the comment for a numerical solution.

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime\prime}\left(  x\right)  +\frac{1}{x}y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)
+y\left(  x\right)    & =0\\
y\left(  0\right)    & =1\\
y^{\prime}\left(  0\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

Let $x=e^{z}$ or $\ln\left(  x\right)  =z$, hence $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}
{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}
=\frac{d^{2}y}{dz^{2}}\frac{dz}{dx}\frac{1}{x}+\frac{dy}{dz}\left(  \frac
{-1}{x^{2}}\right)  =\frac{d^{2}y}{dz^{2}}\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}
\frac{dy}{dz}$

Substituting all these back into the original ODE gives

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^{2}y}{dz^{2}}\frac{1}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{dy}{dz}+\frac{1}
{x}\frac{dy}{dz}\frac{1}{x}+y\left(  z\right)    & =0\\
\frac{d^{2}y}{dz^{2}}+x^{2}y\left(  z\right)    & =0\\
\frac{d^{2}y}{dz^{2}}+e^{2z}y\left(  z\right)    & =0
\end{align*}

The solution to the above is

$$
y\left(  z\right)  = BesselJ_{0}\left(  \sqrt{e^{2z}}\right)
c_{1}+2 BesselY_{0}\left(  \sqrt{e^{2z}}\right)  c_{2}
$$

Replacing back

\begin{equation}
y\left(  x\right)  = BesselJ_{0}\left(  x\right)  c_{1}
+2 BesselY_{0}\left(  x\right)  c_{2}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

You see that there is a `BesselY[0,x]` function in the solution which do not show up the solution given by Mathematica for some reason.

Now to find the constants $c_{1},c_{2}$ we use initial conditions. At $x=0,y=1\,\ $,hence

$$
1=c_{1}-\infty
$$

For the derivative at $x=0$,

$$
y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)  =- BesselJ_{1}\left(  x\right)
c_{1}-2 BesselY_{1}\left(  x\right)  c_{2}
$$

At $x=0$

$$
0=0-\infty
$$

```
sol = DSolve[{y''[z] + Exp[2 z] y[z] == 0}, y[z], z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Btw, Maple 17 gives a numerical solution for this, without the 1/0 issue. But I am not sure how it avoided the point $x=0$ now. It uses RK45 standard numerical method. Here it is:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks so much! Brilliant idea to make change of variables, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"`, provided the denominators are cleared from the equation.

```
ndsol = NDSolve[{x y''[x] + y'[x] + x y[x] == 0,
   y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 10},
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
```

Check with `DSolve`:

```
dsol = DSolve[{x y''[x] + y'[x] + x y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0},
    y[x], {x, 0, 10}];

Plot[y[x] /. Join[dsol, ndsol] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

In this case MMa won't do it directly, but we can use L'Hospital's rule to find the value of the undefined term at `x = 0`.

The undefined term is `y'[x]]/x` and taking the derivative of numerator and denominator gives us

```
y''[x]/1
```

and the PDE  at `x = 0` becomes

```
y''[0] + y''[0]/1 + y[0] == 0 /. y[0] -> 1

Solve[%, y''[0]] // Flatten
(*{(y''[0] -> -(1/2)}*)
```

which tells us that the limit of `y'[x]/x` as `x -> 0` is -1/2, so we can form a Piecewise expression for the PDE.

```
pde = y''[x] + Piecewise[{{-1/2, x == 0}, {y'[x]/x, x > 0}}] + y[x] == 0
```

Now NDSolve has no problem at `x = 0`

```
sol = NDSolve[{pde, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}] // Flatten;
```

And we get a match to the J0 solution.

```
Plot[{BesselJ[0, x], y[x] /. sol}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]